# Vue custom webpack css does not take effect, but it is normal in the vuecli project

Tags: css, vue.js

My same css is used normally in a vuecli project, and the error report in a custom webpack project has no effect. What should I do?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your CSS loader doesn't support the space-separated syntax of `rgb()` (introduced in *CSS Colors Level 4*).

As a workaround, switch to the classic comma-separated syntax:

```css
box-shadow: 0 2px 12px 0 rgb(0, 0, 0, 10%);
```

```css
h1 {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 12px 0 rgb(0, 0, 0, 10%);
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello world</h1>
```